# Angular: Block-scoped declarations not yet supported outside strict mode in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, angular

I am following the [Angular Tour of Heroes tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/).

I am receiving the following error immediately in Chrome browser (v47) upon loading the application localhost:3000. The same application does not produce an error in Firefox (v45):

> SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class)
>   not yet supported outside strict mode at eval (native) at
>   SystemJSLoader.__exec
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1555:18)
>   at entry.execute
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:4035:18)
>   at linkDynamicModule
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3300:32)
>   at link
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3135:11)
>   at Object.execute
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3510:13)
>   at doDynamicExecute
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:766:25)
>   at link
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:964:20)
>   at doLink
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:623:7)
>   at updateLinkSetOnLoad
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:669:18)
>   at
>   http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:485:11
>   at ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:334:26) at
>   Zone.run
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:126:43) at
>   http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:713:57 at
>   ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:367:31)

This is the tsconfig.json file being used (as supplied in the tutorial):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `"alwaysStrict":true` to your tsconfig. As it says in error you need to use strict mode and this option will do it for you.

```
'use strict';
```

Comment: 'use strict' was added to the compiled JavaScript files but sadly the same error was reported